# Customizing a Listbox - How to pass a Listbox Reference to a Converter from within an ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a list of objects with properties `Name` and `Value` which are shown in a listbox. The list is ordered by `Name` and i need to show the sum of the values of all preceeding objects in a third column of my `Listbox`.

I created an `ItemTemplate` from where i call a `ListItemConverter` which is supposed to convert any `ListItem` into the required `double` value by accessing the parent `Listbox`. I can pass the current `ListItem` (or rather the according `ContentPresenter`) to my converter as

```
RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
```

However the ListItem does not contain the information of the whole `Listbox` (which seems quite obvious when i state it this way), so i need to pass a reference to my `Listbox` (or the list which i use as `ItemSource`) to the Converter as well.

How do i pass a second parameter to my converter and how can i access the parent `Listbox` as a Resource from within my `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: Perhaps this is a job for your ViewModel, as opposed to your View.

Comment: It is in fact a job for the view in my case since i will modify the listbox further later on to show a chart instead of the number. I want this to always represent my basic data, so i don't want another property in my viewmodel which in theory could be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

1. Create third property in your item class, or create new Item class with Name, Value and Sum properties. Use this especially in mvvm scenarios
2. Use MultiConverter and MultiBinding:

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock>
                   <TextBlock.Text>
                       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourMultiConverter}">
                           <Binding />
                           <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}" />
                       </MultiBinding>
                   </TextBlock.Text>
               </TextBlock>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   ```

Comment: This is what i tried, but i didn't use MultiBinding properly before - thank you!